# Multiple new's and one delete

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism

If DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2 are classes derived from BaseClass, where BaseClass is a polymorphic class, which of these two code snippets are correct?

```
BaseClass *ptr;

ptr = new DerivedClass1;
ptr->PrintName();

ptr = new DerivedClass2;
ptr->PrintName();

delete ptr;
```

or

```
BaseClass *ptr;

ptr = new DerivedClass1;
ptr->PrintName();

delete ptr;

ptr = new DerivedClass2;
ptr->PrintName();

delete ptr;
```

Does using 'new' multiple times before using 'delete' simply redefine ptr's value, or does it cause some kind of memory leak? Excuse me if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't seem to find an answer to it.

Comment: Manual delete are a sign you are not using C++ correctly. Prefer to place pointers inside a smart pointer to manage it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example will certainly leak. Your second example could leak, say if `PrintName()` threw an exception.

A better idea is to use a smart pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> ptr;

ptr.reset(new DerivedClass1);
ptr->PrintName();

ptr.reset(new DerivedClass2);
ptr->PrintName();
```

Look, Ma, no delete!

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm wondering though, instead of using ptr = new DerivedClass1; do you have to use ptr.reset(new DerivedClass1); ? The first one gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The second is correct. The first leaks an instance of `DerivedClass1`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure the second one is correct. The first results in memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's a leak (in fact, it's both a memory leak *and* a lifetime leak). When you assign a value to a pointer variable, you lose the previously held value, and thus the pointer to the first dynamic object. Each dynamic object (i.e. object created with a `new` expression) must be destroyed manually (usually by a `delete` expression):

```
ptr = new Derived1;
delete ptr;
ptr = new Derived2;
delete ptr;
```